# MongoDB "Operation not permitted Raw" in a container on Azure WebApp with persistent storage

Tags: mongodb, azure-web-app-service

Using Azure WebApp i have set the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE` and added

```
volumes:
- ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/data:/home/data
```

to the docker-compose.yaml file.

I can see the directory being populated by mongo files, yet the console shows `"Operation not permitted Raw:... ***aborting after fassert() failure"` when trying to launch `mongod --dbpath /home/data`

I also noticed i can't change the folders permissions which are set to `drwxrwxrwx   2 nobody nogroup`.

Why is the mongod process crashing even tough it Can write files to the persistent storage?

Thank You.

Comment: Try to add double-quotes `- "${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/data:/home/data"`

Comment: same error :(  what really puzzles me is that it can write to the persistent storage yet gives me the error. (if i try on a local dir it works fine)

Comment: tried storage persistence with an Azure Storage account but received the same results.

Comment: Sorry to ask this 3 years later @TesterBoy - but did you ever solve this?  I'm having a very similar problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573836/mongodb-in-azure-app-service-via-docker-compose) and I'm literally running out of hair to tear out :|